# Trying to create simple bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to convert a large excel into a big bibtex bibliography. I'm running a sample first. I run my code, but it doesn't look as it should.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
@article{article1, 
author={Sell, Ralph R.}, 
title={TRANSFERRED JOBS.}, 
journal={Work and Occupations},
volume={10}, 
number={2}, 
year={1983},
pages={179-206}
}
\end{document}
```

which prints

```
References
@articlearticle1, author=Sell, Ralph R., title=TRANSFERRED JOBS., journal=Work and Occupations, volume=10, number=2, year=1983, pages=179- 206
```

What are I missing?

Comment: The `@article{...}` stuff should go to a separate file called `mybib.bib` and compiled with `bibtex`

Comment: So how would I tell my editor TextPad, where the .bib file is and to print it?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use such editors

Answer (score 2):

This automatically writes a `mynewbib.bib` file and puts the content between `\begin{filecontents}...\end{filecontents}` there. If `mynewbib.bib` already exists, nothing will be (over)written.

I added a citation of `article1` and compiled this document called `foo.tex` with

1. pdflatex foo
2. bibtex foo
3. pdflatex foo

Compiling twice with `pdflatex` is important and necessary to get the references and the input of the bib - stuff correct.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{mynewbib.bib}
@article{article1, 
author={Sell, Ralph R.}, 
title={TRANSFERRED JOBS.}, 
journal={Work and Occupations},
volume={10}, 
number={2}, 
year={1983},
pages={179-206}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{article1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mynewbib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I used the `abstract.bst` as given in the comment below, the output will be this

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how I would add this format? http://get-software.net/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/abstract.bst

Comment: Should be `\bibliographystyle{abstract}` then. Make sure to place `abstract.bst` in your local directory then

Comment: @PhillipBlack: I tried your `abstract.bst`. As I wrote before: Use `\bibliographystyle{abstract}` then. Please note, that `abstract.bst` is already contained in a standard TeXLive (and MikTeX too?) setup, so there's no need to place that file in a local working directory